Is Repeated Measure MANOVA appropriate here?
I have data on the yearly number of doctor visits for patients from 2020 to 2022, along with characteristics associated with these visits. During each visit, patients are asked questions about their smoking status (whether they have smoked in the past 3 months – yes/no) and their drinking status (whether they have had an alcoholic drink in the past 3 months – yes/no). Additionally, I have information on each patient’s age group (<20, 20-24, 25-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60+), and sex (Male/Female).
I want to investigate whether the mean number of doctor visits differs between age groups over time. To do this, I’ve aggregated the data for each patient by year, including the number of visits and the prevalence of smoking and drinking reported during those visits. For example, if a patient visited the doctor 5 times in 2020 and reported smoking during 3 of those visits, their smoking prevalence for 2020 would be 3/5 (60%).
The data is set up like:



Patient
Age Group
Sex
Visits in 2020
2020 % Smoking
2020 % Drinking
Visits in 2021
2021 % Smoking
2021 % Drinking
Visits in 2022
2022 % Smoking
2022 % Drinking




1
25-29
Male
5
0.60
0.80
2
0.50
1.0
3
0.667
1.0


2
30-39
Female
1
0.0
1.0
0
0.0
0.0
0
0.0
0.0


3
50-59
Male
0
0.0
0.0
1
0.0
0.0
3
0.0
0.33



Using this dataset, I am interested in examining how the average number of doctor visits per year changes over time across different age groups, while controlling for smoking and drinking behaviors.
Would RM MANCOVA be an appropriate method to analyze this data?

ANOVA-type methods aren't a good choice here, as your outcome variable is a small number of counts per year. ANOVA is designed for continuous outcome variables. Also, I think that you are throwing away a lot of useful information by your binning of ages into decades and of visit dates  into numbers per year. For example, when you evaluate the smoking/drinking status as a fraction of visits each year during which smoking/drinking was reported, your smoking variable will necessarily depend on how many visits the patient made in a year.
It sounds like this would be better handled by evaluating the actual visit dates themselves with a repeated-events "survival" model. That's outlined in Section 2.2 of the R survival vignette. Your data setup would have one row per patient for each period between visits, with notations of the patient ID, the start and stop times of the period, and an "event" marker of whether that stop time was an actual visit (1, for an "event") or just the last known time that the patient was available for a visit (0, for a "right censored" time, a minimum value for the time of the next visit). For each time period you would also include age, sex, and smoking/drinking status at the start of the time period.
With that setup you could use a "survival" model (e.g., a Cox proportional hazards model, as explained in the vignette) to evaluate whether the time between visits (technically, the "hazard" of making another visit) is associated with your predictors. You would have to choose whether to count time from the first time the patient was seen for all visits, or to reset the "start" time to 0 at each visit and have the "stop" time be the duration until the next visit. Those have different interpretations.
If you don't have access to the disaggregated data, your next best choice would be a generalized linear model appropriate for counts, perhaps a Poisson regression.
Finally, this type of data often has death as an event "competing" with the event of another visit. If someone dies during the year, then your data on that person won't cover the whole year. That might be handled in a couple of different ways. I'd suggest consulting with an experienced local statistician who could go through the details of your study more comprehensively than is possible on this site.

Thanks so much for your comment! This is extremely helpful. In terms of constructing a survival function, I have absolutely considered this. To do this is seems like the most appropriate models would be cox models that handle repeated measures. The Prentice Williams Peterson (PWP) model sounds sufficient. However, it requires the doctors visits to be stratified. Since I have lots of data (Doctors visits for multiple years), I can see the stratified cox models constructed for the latter groups of individuals with lots of events not being sound.

@Kevin there are always problems with model imprecision at late event times even in single-event survival models, as there are typically few individuals still at risk at late times. That's not conceptually different from your situation, in which you have few individuals in the strata representing the greater numbers of visits. There isn't really a way around that problem, but the PWP model will almost certainly be more informative than a model of annually grouped count data.
